# Can I use CSS :hover to effect another elements properties?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am attempting to change a text links properties (different colour and text-decoration:underline;) when hovering over its corresponding image.

This is the html:

```
<!-- Wraps image, title, category -->
                <div class="itemWrap">
                    <!-- Item Image -->
                    <a href="#" class="itemImageLink"><img class="itemImage" src="img/thumb.png" alt="thumb"></a>
                    <!-- Item Title -->
                    <div class="itemTitle">
                        <a href="#">The original soul of Michael Jackson</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Item Category -->
                    <div class="itemCat">
                        <a href="#">12" Picture Disc</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- close itemWrap -->
```

Is it possible that when hovering over the itemImage (which is encased in an anchor) that the properties of a link within .itemTitle can be changed?

It might be worth noting that the itemWrap is used multiple times on the webpage.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:hover` anywhere in a compound selector, so if you can select the elements you want to change while including `:hover`, then yes.

In this case, you can't really do it with `itemImage` because it involves backtracking up the DOM, but you can do it with `itemImageLink`, for instance:

```
.itemImageLink:hover ~ .itemTitle {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method which doesn't work. I am trying to change the properties of the link inside the .itemTitle class which would make it a child(?) element of .itemTitle, would this be possible?

Comment: I solved this using a combination of sibling and descendant selectors.

Comment: @crm the above answer correctly answers your original question... The problem you solved deals with [css specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my specific problem, but thanks for other peoples attempts.

I had to use a combination of the **sibling** and **descendant** selectors.

I applied the psuedo `:hover` to the anchor around the image and selected the next sibling by the name of `.itemTitle` and then .itemTitle's descendant `.itemTitleLink`.

```
.itemImageLink:hover ~ .itemTitle > .itemTitleLink {color:#CD3333;text-decoration:underline;}

<a href="#" class="itemImageLink">
<div class="itemTitle"><!-- sibling of .itemImageLink -->
    <a href="#" class="itemTitleLink">Link</a><!-- descendant of .itemTitle -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, you solved problem when user hovering over IMAGE visually (that is actually `itemImageLink` class), but not when hovering over `itemImage` class. In other words - this solved your problem, but this is not answer to your question.